# Docker Desktop 4.16.3 fails to start with error 'provisioning docker WSL distros: terminating WSL distro \"docker-desktop" '

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

There are a lot of questions on the topic of Docker Desktop failing to start but as far as I've found no one has addressed this specific error (below formatting has been modified to make easier to read

```
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
{"message":"1 error occurred:\n\t* provisioning docker WSL distros: terminating WSL distro \"docker-desktop\":
terminating WSL distro \"docker-desktop\": exit status 0xffffffff\n\n"}

   at Docker.Core.GoBackend.GoBackendClient.<PostNoBodyWithError>d__19.MoveNext() in 
C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\GoBackend\GoBackendClient.cs:line 226
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in
C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in 
C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in 
C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in 
C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in 
C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 72
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__23.MoveNext() in 
C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 109
```

This problem appears to be related to a recent Docker Desktop update (for Windows) and 4.16.2 and 4.16.3 where released in part to fix the issue, see for example [Docker Desktop Will Not Start #13184](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13184). However, the issue continues (I am running 4.16.3).

One could uninstall and reinstall Docker but if you are looking to preserve your existing containers, volumes, etc. that isn't ideal.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a number of different ways to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. The one that finally worked was two-fold.

1: [diablodale](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13184#issuecomment-1407054437) noticed (as I had) that `docker-desktop` was stuck in an `Uninstalling` state. They suggested manually unregistering the system distro (e.g. view PowerShell or Command Prompt):

```
wsl --unregister docker-desktop
```

2. Check that this completed successfully:

```
wsl -l -v --all
```

This unfortunately didn't initially work for me, it was [qst2's comment](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13184#issuecomment-1415127944) that they had:

3. Shut down WSL:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

4. Then restarted Docker Desktop.

Hope this helps someone else.

## Recurrence, 2/22/23

Rebooted my Windows system and when it came back up Docker Desktop was again failing to start. The message was different this time (but related):

```
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
{"message":"1 error occurred:\n\t* starting WSL integration 
service: synchronising agents: starting added distros: 1 error 
occurred:\n\t* waiting for WSL integration for Ubuntu-22.04: 
timed out while polling for WSL distro integration to become 
ready in \"Ubuntu-22.04\"\n\n\n\n"}
```

This time the issue was fixed by executing steps 3 and 4 from above.